# How to validate array items in Symfony 2.3?

Tags: php, validation, symfony, symfony-2.3

I use Symfony v2.3.x and I have a validation file that looks something like this:

```
Namespace\To\MyEntity:
    properties:
        entityCollection:
            - Type: { groups: [mygroup], type: array }
            - All:
                constraints:
                    - Type: { groups: [mygroup], type: Namespace\To\AnotherEntity }
```

So `MyEntity` must contain an array of `AnotherEntity`s in the `entityCollection` field.

It successfully validates that `entityCollection` must be an array. However, it fails to validate that the elements of that array are of the specified type.

For example, these two `var_dump`s both show the value `0` on the screen even though I expect something non-zero:

```
$obj = new MyEntity();
$obj->entityCollection = array(12345);
$errors = $symfonyValidator->validate($obj, array('mygroup'));
var_dump(count($errors));

$obj = new MyEntity();
$obj->entityCollection = array("something");
$errors = $symfonyValidator->validate($obj, array('mygroup'));
var_dump(count($errors));
```

I even tried removing the `constraints` entry from the validation file; it made no difference.

I looked at [Symfony's official page about the `All` keyword](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/reference/constraints/All.html) but I couldn't find anything that would work.

How should I modify the entry in my `validation.yml` file so that the validation works as intended ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "considered valid"? Are you saying that the `isValid()` method of your form object returns `true`?

Comment: @HaigBedrosian I edited my question to make it clearer :) .

Answer (score 0):

Your configs look fine, although I'm more accustomed to having them as annotations so it's clear what entity properties they apply to. Have you tried:

```
$errors = $symfonyValidator->validate($obj, array('mygroup'), true);
```

The 3rd parameter to the `validate()` method is a boolean for traversing the object you're validating.

```
bool    $traverse   Whether to traverse the value if it is traversable.
```

[Symfony Validator API v2.3](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Validator/Validator.html#method_validate)

Comment: Hmmm, haven't thought about that. I will try it and let you know, thanks :) .

Comment: I changed it to `$symfonyValidator->validate($obj, array('mygroup'), true);` and to `$symfonyValidator->validate($obj, array('mygroup'), true, true);`. It doesn't work, it keeps saying that everything is valid. This is a really strange problem...

Comment: Well there are only 2 constraints - the validation group and the entity type. So ... does eliminating the validation group have any effect?